# Need to save image into the gallery folder of Phone Memory(Not SD Card)

Tags: android

I need to create a folder in the default gallery folder of the phone menory(Not SD Card).After that I need to save the Image into a folder(creating it in gallery folder) using the camera.

The problem is that I can find the default galley folder in the SDcard and I can create the folder and save images into it.

But with the phone memory I can't see the default gallery folder .Is there any way to see the gallery folder in the phone memory.And also how to create folder and save images into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create folder in internal memory like this

```
    File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); 
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir);
```

And than while saving file on folder,give path to this directory and Check O/P

Answer (score 0):

this line add your image in gallery:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

Note that your must also add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to your manifext.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can create Folder and saved images into Internal Memory(Phone Memory). But,any one can't see those folder as well as image too. That is the purpose of internal memory in android

Answer (score 0):

```
To create and write a private file to the internal storage:

   1. Call openFileOutput() with the name of the file and the operating mode. This returns a FileOutputStream.
   2. Write to the file with write().
   3. Close the stream with close().

For example:

String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();


Refer the link...............                

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal
```